# Swagger identifies rare endpoints in REST API

Tags: swagger, eclipselink, openapi, java-ee-8

Some days ago I started a REST API in JavaEE 7, I implemented a single class with three methods and implemented succesfully Swagger and Swagger-UI in the project, which showed the three endpoints I implemented succesfully in the generated JSON.

However, I migrated to JavaEE 8, and after this change Swagger detects several unknown endpoints, like the "default" ones (this capture shows only part of all of them):

[image: Some endpoints]

Investigating a bit I discovered that these endpoints may belong to a JPA REST API in Eclipselink implementation, as described here https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-rest-data-services-ords-open-api-swagger-support and here https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/solutions/restful_jpa004.htm#CHDFCFFA
Despite they appear in the generated JSON, all of them contain variable paths, so I can't access them following the path given by Swagger, even inventing some parameters like "version" using the webs above examples.

The Swagger version I use is v3, aka OpenAPI version. I specify OpenAPI properties with `@OpenAPIDefinition` in the endpoint class, which also contains a `@Tag` annotation to group them and the three methods contain `@Operation` tag with their own `@ApiResponse`. There is no more Swagger/OpenAPI annotations/files/classes written by me.

The question is, how can I make Swagger ignoring these endpoints?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Finally I have found a solution. The case is that Swagger scanner engine scans the whole project, ignoring if the class and his methods have @Operation or not. If my hypothesis is true, some Eclipselink classes could have Swagger annotations (I'm not sure), so when Swagger scans, if finds them and add them to the JSON/YAML.
The solution is creating/adding to the existant openapi.yaml (it can have several names and can be in several locations, as enumerated here: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Integration-and-configuration#known-locations) this:

```
resourceClasses:
- com.path.to.your.package.Resource
prettyPrint: true
cacheTTL: 0 
scannerClass: io.swagger.v3.jaxrs2.integration.JaxrsAnnotationScanner
readAllResources: false
```

Instead of `resourceClasses` it can be written `resourcePackages`, and then it should be specified the whole package and the class in the same style as used to specify the package. To be honest, this property does not affect to my problem.
The solution comes on setting `readAllResources` to `false`. The reason is here, in a note: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Annotations#operation

> Blockquote
>   Note: swagger-jaxrs2 reader engine includes by default also methods of scanned resources which are not annotated with @Operation, as long as a jax-rs @Path is defined at class and/or method level, together with the http method annotation (@GET, @POST, etc).

I hope this solution serves for anyone if he/she has to face the same problem.